# Sum seems to double/triple count when left joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, left-join

I am trying to join two tables (inventory and sales) on an identification number, and sum the quantity of the goods in inventory, the inventory value, and the sales value/volume. This is grouped by part number.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
`select inv.[num]
, sum(inv.[Value]) as [Inventory Value]
, sum(inv.[qty]) as [Inventory Qty]
, sum(sales.[Value]) as [Sales Value]
, sum(sales.[qty]) as [Sales qty]
from Inv
left join sales
on inv.[num]=sales.[num]
group by inv.[num]`
```

The inventory value summation is about 50x too big, sales about 3 or 4 times too big.
How can I keep from over summing?

Comment: What is happening is referred to as "fanning".  Can you show us some sample data so we can determine which is the best way to fix it?  Either aggregating Inv or Sales on their own should solve it.

Comment: try adding `where sales.num is not null`. Anyways the above comment gives you correct answer

Comment: This is because `inv.[num]=sales.[num]` is not a one-to-one match.  Each row in `Inv` is getting paired with multiple rows from `sales` and you are summing the `[Value]` from all those combinations.

Answer (score 0):

When using `group by` with joins that are many-to-one or many-to-many, you should first aggregate the measures and join on the dimensions.

```
select
    inv_agg.inv_num as 'Inventory Number'
    ,inv_agg.inv_value as 'Inventory Value'
    ,inv_agg.inv_qty as 'Inventory Qty'
    ,sales_agg.sales_value as 'Sales Value'
    ,sales_agg.sales_qty as 'Sales Qty'
from (select 
        inv.num as inv_num
        ,sum(inv.Value) as inv_value
        ,sum(inv.qty) as inv_qty
    from inv
    group by inv.num) inv_agg
left join (select
        sales.num sales_num
        ,sum(sales.Value) as sales_value
        ,sum(sales.qty) as sales_qty
    from sales
    group by sales.num) sales_agg
on inv_agg.inv_num = sales_agg.sales_num
```

Or, with CTE's

```
with inv_agg as (select 
        inv.num as inv_num
        ,sum(inv.Value) as inv_value
        ,sum(inv.qty) as inv_qty
    from inv
    group by inv.num),
sales_agg as (select
        sales.num sales_num
        ,sum(sales.Value) as sales_value
        ,sum(sales.qty) as sales_qty
    from sales
    group by sales.num)
select
    inv_agg.inv_num as 'Inventory Number'
    ,inv_agg.inv_value as 'Inventory Value'
    ,inv_agg.inv_qty as 'Inventory Qty'
    ,sales_agg.sales_value as 'Sales Value'
    ,sales_agg.sales_qty as 'Sales Qty'
from inv_agg left join sales_agg
    on inv_agg.inv_num = sales_agg.sales_num
```